# One function for several objects

Tags: javascript, function

I have lately joined the big incremental/IDLE wave, and wanted to just make a little project with Javascript at the same time to learn it more and stop following tutorials like a slave, and try to learn as I do, and use my old skills.

I will say I'm decent to google stuff, but this time, I capitulated to make a question. Couldn't find the right words or "syntax" to google.

This is my problem:

I have an object(?):

```
var weapon = {
    stick:      { cost: 50, attack: 1, owned: 0 },
    mace:       { cost: 250, attack: 5, owned: 0 },
    sword:      { cost: 1000, attack: 15, owned: 0 },
    bow:        { cost: 4000, attack: 50, owned: 0 }
};
```

This are like my "upgrades".

```
<button onclick='buyWeapon("stick")' class="btn btn-info btn-block">BUY STICK (COST: <span id="stickCost">x</span>)</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick='buyWeapon(stick)' class="btn btn-info btn-block">BUY STICK (COST: <span id="stickCost">x</span>)</button>
```

This is how I "want" to buy them, with this function:

```
function buyWeapon(foo) {
    if ( gamedata.player.currency >= weapon.foo.cost ) {
        gamedata.player.currency -= weapon.foo.cost;
        weapon.foo.owned++;
        weapon.foo.cost *= 1.10;
        gamedata.player.attack += weapon.foo.attack;
    } else {
        window.alert("Not enough cash!");
    };
};
```

When I try this I get this in the JS-console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: stick is not defined

this one without " "

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined

this one with the " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use quotes properly in your `onclick` attributes.

```
<button onclick="buyWeapon('stick')" class="btn btn-info btn-block">BUY STICK (COST: <span id="stickCost">x</span>)</button>
```

The problem you are having there is that without the quotes around `stick` it's being treated as a variable instead of a string.

Second, in the `buyWeapon` function, you need to reference the objects in the weapon object properly.

```
weapon[foo].cost
```

If you do `weapon.foo.cost` then are looking up attribute `foo` in `weapon`, but what you really want is to find an attribute in `weapon` that matches the value of `foo` so we do `weapon[foo]`. It's called bracket notation. You can [read more about the differences on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: When I read this, I actually realize the answer, cause I have seen this so many this in another contex. But thanks for a fast answer. So now my next thing to do is get rid of the big float's ^^,